# Strange python syntax, or in print statement

Tags: python, syntax

I can't find anything about this, so I'm forced to ask here. I'm sure it's an easy question for anybody who knows python well.

python 2:

```
print raw_input() == 0 or hash(tuple(map(int, raw_input().split(' '))))
```

python 3:

```
print(input()==0 or hash(tuple(map(int,input().strip().split()))))
```

I am trying to understand why an 'or' is in a print statement.
The code in question has a boolean operator inside a print statement, comparing a boolean and an int. This is what I need explained to me. It is obviously specific to python. What would the code print in the case that input()==0 returns true? How can we compare a boolean and a hash, and again, what are we doing making boolean comparisons inside a print statement?

Comment: Is this Python2 or Python3? It makes a difference.

Comment: None of the answers so far make clear the part of this which is unusual (but not unique, JS also does this) which is not how print works, or short-circuiting, but that `or` doesn't always evaluate to a boolean, but retains the type of the tested values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, comparisons with `or` or `and` make use of two features:

1. [Truthy and falsey values](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), and
2. [Short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

So, when you have something like this:

```
print(input()==0 or hash(tuple(map(int,input().strip().split()))))
```

It'll follow the order of operations, checking whether `input()` returns a `0`. Since it's that `or` the next term, if it's true then the next term has no impact on the result and won't be evaluated. If that happens, it'll print `True`, since that's what's returned by `input()==0`.

If that's false, it'll evaluate the next part, getting input, mapping it as an integer, turning it into a tuple, and hashing it. It'll then return that hash whether or not it's a truthy value (a number other than `0`, a sequence or set with contents, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Python will first evaluate whether or not `input()==0` is `True`. If it is, then Python will print it and ignore the rest of the line. If the input is not equal to 0 and this evaluates as `False`, then it will be ignored and the rest of the line will be printed *regardless of how it evaluates*. So even if the rest of the line would evaluate as `False`, Python will print its result.

A clearer example would be setting the name of something based on user input and requiring a default value.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
print ("So your name is...")
print (name or "John Smith")
```

`name` will be evaluated as `True` or `False`. Since an empty string will be considered `False`, if the user enters nothing then instead Python will print the default name after the `or` operator.

Comment: I understand now entirely what this does. Thank you. Now, is it just me, or is this syntax completely illogical. Sure, I can memorize it, but it behaves more like (if name print name, else print "John Smith"). The or statement is illogical it seems?

Comment: @ChrisStPierre It's definitely odd but I feel like it makes sense because you're telling Python do this OR this. I think it depends on how much you're willing to read it as if it's just a sentence in English. I've never actually used it though, I've used `x if True else y` because it's more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your code is Python3, since otherwise it is unlikely that the result of `input()` would have a `strip` method.

Here is a long form of the code, with explanations.

```
# Read a line of input. Returns a string.
a = input()
# Compare to integer 0, always False.
# Effectively, this ignores the first line of input.
b = a == 0
# Separate function to represent lazy evaluation.
def y():
    # Get a second line of input, as a string.
    c = input()
    # Strip leading and trailing whitespace, still a string.
    # This line is useless since split() with no argument does this.
    d = c.strip()
    # Split the line by any runs of whitespace. Returns a list of strings.
    e = d.split()
    # For each string in the list, convert it to an integer in base 10.
    # Return an iterator (not list) of ints.
    # Most people would write (int(s) for x in e) for a generator
    # comprehension, or [int(s) for x in e] for a list comprehension.
    m = map(int, e)
    # Consume the iterator into a tuple of ints.
    # Note that it can't be a list, because lists aren't hashable.
    t = tuple(m)
    # Hash the tuple, returning a single int.
    return hash(t)
# If b is truthy, set x to it. Otherwise, evaluate y() and set x to that.
# Unlike many languages, the arguments to or are *not* coerced to bool.
# Since b is False, y() will be evaluated.
x = b or y()
# Print the result of y().
# i.e. the hash of the tuple of ints on the second line.
# This is essentially a meaningless number.
print(x)
```